# How to compare columns from two data frames segmented by another column and mark repeated entries?

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have two data frames `baseline1` and `baseline2`, both containing the same batch of participants and their responses on certain test items. The participants are the same and some of the items they had to respond in baseline1 and baseline2 are actually repeated. How do I mark these repeated items for every participant?

Let's say the data is like this:

```
set.seed(100)
participants1 <- rep(1:5, each = 5)
items1 <- sample(letters[seq(from = 1, to = 5)], size = 25, replace = TRUE) 
responses1 <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 7, by = 1), size = 25, replace = TRUE) 
baseline1 <- data.frame(participant = participants1, item = items1, response = responses1)
set.seed(110)
items2 <- sample(letters[seq(from = 3, to = 7)], size = 25, replace = TRUE) 
responses2 <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 7, by = 1), size = 25, replace = TRUE) 
baseline2 <- data.frame(participant = participants1, item = items2, response = responses2)
```

So the two data frames look like this:

baseline1

```
   participant item response
1            1    b        2
2            1    c        6
3            1    a        5
4            1    b        5
5            1    d        6
6            2    d        6
7            2    b        5
8            2    c        7
9            2    b        7
10           2    e        1
11           3    d        7
12           3    c        5
13           3    c        4
14           3    b        3
15           3    a        7
16           4    b        6
17           4    c        1
18           4    d        1
19           4    d        1
20           4    d        6
21           5    e        3
22           5    c        7
23           5    a        7
24           5    c        1
25           5    d        1
```

baseline2

```
   participant item response
1            1    f        3
2            1    e        6
3            1    c        3
4            1    e        6
5            1    c        5
6            2    e        1
7            2    f        3
8            2    e        4
9            2    e        5
10           2    d        7
11           3    d        3
12           3    c        2
13           3    d        4
14           3    c        1
15           3    g        1
16           4    f        1
17           4    f        5
18           4    c        1
19           4    g        6
20           4    c        6
21           5    f        6
22           5    d        2
23           5    d        4
24           5    f        2
25           5    d        6
```

I need to mark repeated items for **every** participant. Thus marking row 2 in baseline 1, also row 3 and row 5 in baseline 2 ("c" is the repeated item for participant 1). So forth and so on for other participants. I was thinking something like this:

```
repeats <- aggregate(baseline1$item, by = list(baseline1$participant), 
           function(x) x %in% baseline2$item)
baseline1$repeated <- repeats
```

But of course it doesn't work, since I need a way to split the "item" vector in baseline2 based on the participant variable as well.

Is there any way to do it with `aggregate`? If not, how about other functions or ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned that all the participants are present in both the dataframes, we can `merge` `baseline1` and `baseline2` based on `c("participant", "item")` to create `match_df`. We then `split` `match_df` and baseline to create a `duplicate` column in both the dataframe.

```
match_df <- unique(merge(baseline1, baseline2, by = c("participant", "item"))[1:2])

baseline1$duplicate <-c(mapply(`%in%`,split(baseline1$item, baseline1$participant), 
                          split(match_df$item, match_df$participant)))

baseline2$duplicate <-c(mapply(`%in%`,split(baseline2$item, baseline2$participant), 
                         split(match_df$item, match_df$participant)))


head(baseline1)
#      participant item response duplicate
#1           1    b        2     FALSE
#2           1    c        6      TRUE
#3           1    a        5     FALSE
#4           1    b        5     FALSE
#5           1    d        6     FALSE
#6           2    d        6      TRUE

head(baseline2)
#      participant item response duplicate
#1           1    f        3     FALSE
#2           1    e        6     FALSE
#3           1    c        3      TRUE
#4           1    e        6     FALSE
#5           1    c        5      TRUE
#6           2    e        1      TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

First I search for `participant` and `item` which are in `baseline1` and `baseline2` and stor it in `tt`. Then you simply have to ask with `%in%` if `participant` and `item` are in `tt`.

```
tt <- unique(interaction(baseline1[1:2]))
tt <- tt[tt %in% unique(interaction(baseline2[1:2]))]

baseline1$repeated <- interaction(baseline1[1:2]) %in% tt
baseline2$repeated <- interaction(baseline2[1:2]) %in% tt

head(baseline1)
#  participant item response repeated
#1           1    b        2    FALSE
#2           1    c        6     TRUE
#3           1    a        5    FALSE
#4           1    b        5    FALSE
#5           1    d        6    FALSE
#6           2    d        6     TRUE

head(baseline2)
#  participant item response repeated
#1           1    f        3    FALSE
#2           1    e        6    FALSE
#3           1    c        3     TRUE
#4           1    e        6    FALSE
#5           1    c        5     TRUE
#6           2    e        1     TRUE
```

Or you can make it direct like:

```
baseline1$repeated <- interaction(baseline1[1:2]) %in% interaction(baseline2[1:2])
baseline2$repeated <- interaction(baseline2[1:2]) %in% interaction(baseline1[1:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this repository, i have used pandas to compare different colums entries and counted how many times a particular entries have been repeated.
https://github.com/imneonizer/Pandas-Data-Analysis